# Restangular + rails: unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular, grape-api

I want to make a patch request with Restangular to update user atrributes. So, a write this:

```
user.patch(user: user).then(function (result) ...
```

I'm using grape framework in rails and my controller looks like this:

```
desc 'Update a user'
    params do
      requires :user, type: Hash, desc: "user attributes" do
        optional :email, type: String, allow_blank: false, regexp: /.+@.+/, documentation: { example: 'example@hubeert.com' }
        optional :password, type: String, allow_blank: false
        optional :firstname, type: String
        optional :lastname, type: String
        optional :city, type: String
        optional :date_of_birth, type: Date
      end
    end

    patch ':id' do
      puts params.to_h
      user = User.find(params[:id])
      user.update(params[:user].to_h)
      user
    end
```

Unfortunately, i don't have atrribute routes i my user model, so rails shows this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: route):
  app/controllers/api/v1/users.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Users>'
```

What should i do? Delete this atrribute in angular or in rails? It is possible to update model with only params that i choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that it's best to create/update records ONLY with parameters you want to be permitted - and you can easily do this with Grape.

Grape has a handy `declared` method that accepts `params` with optional [include_missing](https://github.com/intridea/grape#include-missing) argument. So you can write a helper that filters out any parameters not declared in `params do ... end` block:

```
def permitted_params
  @permitted_params ||= declared(params, include_missing: false).to_h
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
patch ':id' do
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update(permitted_params[:user])
end
```